# Retrieve dbPool arguments from existing object

Tags: r, odbc, database-connection, azure-synapse, pool

I would like to use the arguments used for the dbPool connection inside another function without having to provide the information again.

I have tried to use dbConnectArgs but I wasn’t able to make it work. I would like to be able to retrieve the ‘database’ and ´server’ arguments from the dbPool connection.

Here is an example of my dbPool connection :

```
connection <- pool::dbPool(
  drv = odbc::odbc(),
  driver = <driver name>,
  database = <database name>,
  UID = <username>,
  PWD = <password>,
  server = <server name>,
  port = <port>,
  minsize = 0,
  idleTimeout = 600,
  encoding = "UTF-8",
  Authentication = <authentication method>,
  encrypt = "yes"
)
```

So I would need to get "database name" and "server name" minimally. Is there a function/method to get this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have found the solution! By evalutating the the connection object we can retrieve a S4 object. Here’s how :

```
object <- eval(connection$fetch())
servername <- object@info$servername
dbname <- object@info$dbname
```